# Linux Kernel Hacking on a Beaglebone (white)

Tags: c, debugging, linux-kernel, arm, beagleboard

tl;dr - How do I build a Linux kernel from source for the beagle bone (white), install it, then debug it?

I am trying to break into kernel hacking - specifically porting an experimental kernel feature that has been implemented on x86 over to ARM. I chose the Beagleboard white as a development platform because of the built in J-Tag over USB.

I want to get a development environment set up using openocd and gdb so that I can debug running kernels, and nail down a routine for building Linux from source and installing it onto the beagle board. I have truly scoured the internet and although I feel like all of the pieces may be out there somewhere, I'm having trouble putting everything together.

I hope that responses to this question might be a roadmap for those who come after me and want to start doing some kernel development on ARM.

Thanks!

Things I have tried:

I have NOT tried CCS5 because, as far as I can tell, it is not open source, does not have a command-line interface, and is not fully supported on Linux.

I HAVE run openOCD. I can halt and resume the processor on the beagle bone through a gdb session connected to the OpenOCD process. I have NOT been able to load any meaningful symbol table into that GDB session and therefore have not been able to break on a system call (a milestone I am shooting for).

I HAVE installed many premade kernel images onto the beagle board and have run through the tutorial at http://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone, but it did not start from stock linux and hid the necessary configuration options to build for the BeagleBone.

I understand my question is broad, but I asked that way by design in the hopes that people who come after me can find a solid starting point rather than specific snippets of info from people who are stuck at various points along the process. If that is not the proper way to use SO, my sincerest apologies.

Comment: Your question consists of at least two independent parts: wiring up openocd and gdb uwing the built-in JTAG, and building Linux from source and installing it on the target. You also do not mention what you have actually tried so far. I would suggest going off to http://beagleboard.org/static/beaglebone/a3/Docs/ccs-jtag-simple.htm, run through that, and make sure you have it working before you start looking at openocd. Kernels are a bit trickier since support is not in mainline. Work through http://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone to start with. Then come back with any specific issues.

Comment: @unixsmurf I updated the question with some of the things I've tried. I've been working on this on and off for a few weeks, so thats not a comprehensive list. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Are you sure that with the caches, etc on you are going to be able to break at the point you want.  the jtag as used here is nothing more than a communication interface with the on chip debugger, if the on chip debugger is unable to do what you want then jtag wont fix that.  Maybe it will.  You may wish to insert an undefined instruction or an swi or something that the processor will slam into with or without the debugger watching.

Comment: You may wish to scrap the beaglebone for now and use qemu. Or maybe stick with the beaglebone and not use gdb but openocd directly through telnet, maybe there are other things you can do that way.  Just some thoughts...

Comment: It is better from an SO perspective to try to keep it to one problem per question (this is what I assume unixsmurf is saying).  Your real question may or may not be getting the symbol table into gdb for example.  You instead have a specific thing you want to break on, ask about that as the real question, with "I tried gdb+openocd like this" as the "what I tried"...the porting of a feature actually is your real question isnt it?  your approach may be quite valid but there may be another approach to reach your ultimate goal.